# Method not found using Web Pages 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to use the Microsoft Web Helpers so I can use the `@Video` helper.  My code looks like this:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;

@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home";
}

@Video.Flash(path: "my_flash_video.swf", width: "400", height: "600",
             play: true, loop: true, menu:  false, bgColor: "red", 
             quality: "medium", scale: "exactfit", windowMode: "transparent")
```

Everytime I run this I get the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult
>   Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash(System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.String)'.

Can anyone shine any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Web Helpers library from the NuGet Package Manager? If no go to your NuGet package manager and install the ASP.NET Web Helpers Library.

Comment: Yes.  But, it still doesn't show up in Web Pages 2.  If I create a Web Pages 1 project, I can use it.